# Okcupid.com (can find matches without accessing a database!?)

Tags: mysql, query

I'm doing a research project on a popular dating site called: [OkCupid](http://www.okcupid.com/about/technology)
I would like to talk about how the database is used.
After reading this explanation from the Co-Founder of the site, I became very confused.
The statements:

> when a user performs a match search on OkCupid, we have to do the
>   following:
>
> -Retrieve **(from somewhere not the DB)** their question answers, their ideal match's answers, and their question importances. On average,
>   each user on OkCupid has 250 questions answered in 3 parts.
>   -Figure out who qualifies for their search, typically a very complicated query across a few million users. On average, tens of
>   thousands of people qualify, and we need to figure out who they are
>   **without hitting the DB.**

How do they do all this without consulting a database??
I'm utterly confused.
[Here is a link to the post](http://www.quora.com/OkCupid/Is-OkCupid-programmed-in-only-C)
I appreciate any explanations as to how they do things there

Answer (score 2):

They didn't explicitly mention this, so I am only guessing here, but they are using some search index such as Lucene to perform the actual searches.  They'll have a persistent database of some sort but their search index is periodically built from that data set.